# Android gradle build: excluded java source files get compiled

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android gradle build: excluded java source files get compiled:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java {

                exclude { element ->
                    element.file.path.endsWith("Foo.java")      
                }
            }

            java.sourceFiles.each { println "file: " + it }
        }
    }
}
```

The Foo.java is excluded from the source set. But android build: still tries to compile Foo.java and emit compiling errors in the Foo.java.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing for a class file which I was working on, but hadn't got it to a state where it would compile, and I needed to build the app without it.

The way that I found to do it is to stash the file somewhere that Android Studio knows about (so that you can see it and edit it), but doesn't expect to find java source files, so it doesn't compile it by default. I used a subdirectory of the assets directory.

Then you can use sourceSets for different build variants with explicit definitions of `res.srcDirs` to make it compile the additional java files when you want it to, like this

```
    sourceSets {
        release {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/...']
        }
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/...',
            'src/main/assets/test']
        }
    }
```

Note that if you do this, it still doesn't seem to report compilation errors in the file(s) under `assets/test` unless there is a reference in the main code to a class defined there. Of course you can create such a reference conditional on `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.