# Class referenced in the manifest, ..., was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This question has been asked before, but none of the solutions offered seems to be useful in my situation, apart from suppressing the error, which seems very inelegant.

I see this error for all of the activities in the app, but the activities are all there and can be seen in the project tool window, and the app compiles and runs without any problems: it's just the error message that's wrong.

I've tried inserting the full package name in front of the class name, which doesn't help, and I've tried invalidating the caches and restarting, which also doesn't help, and doing both of those, which still doesn't help.. The package name is correctly declared in all the class files, and the activities are all `public`.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
   Copyright © 2021. Richard P. Parkins, M. A.
   Released under GPL V3 or later
  -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.yahoo.p1rpp.secondsclock">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupOnly="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <receiver
            android:name=".SecondsClockWidget"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/seconds_clock_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ClockActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="uk.co.yahoo.p1rpp.ClockActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ClockConfigureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="uk.co.yahoo.p1rpp.ClockConfigureActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="uk.co.yahoo.p1rpp.MainActivity" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".WidgetConfigureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="uk.co.yahoo.p1rpp.WidgetConfigureActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container"
            android:value="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Looking further into it, the error message seems to be being provoked by a recent change that I made to use explicit `sourceSet`s in my `build.gradle`, like this:-

```
    sourceSets {
        release {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
        withlater {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/ForLater/',
                           'src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
    }
```

[This was my answer to [Android gradle build: excluded java source files get compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435993/android-gradle-build-excluded-java-source-files-get-compiled/70579438#70579438)]

If I take that bit of code out, I don't get the error messages, but why is it reporting an error when there really isn't one. It looks as if perhaps the inspection for missing class isn't correctly accounting for explicit `sourceSet`s, even though the actual gradle build understands them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This change fixes the error message from the manifest:-

```
    sourceSets {
        release {
            //res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
        debug {
            //res.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
        withlater {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/ForLater/',
                           'src/main/java/uk/co/yahoo/p1rpp/secondsclock']
        }
    }
```

If I don't specify `res.srcDirs` explicitly, it uses the default one and finds the activity classes. However the code in `src/main/assets/ForLater` doesn't get inspected for errors.